# SSR with Helmet also render async meta and content?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I'm trying to build an app where needs to get data before send props to `<Helmet>` but I don't know if it's possible because I don't see nothing like it in the docs.

And there's no possible to show this content in Helmet component. The content is always `empty`

The `Helmet`  component is the `HtmlPage` component.
In the code below, we receive an `SEO undefined` error.

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/409

```
<HtmlPage
    {...this.props.client.info.SEO}
>

    <ThemeProvider theme={this.state.theme}>
        <div className='wrapper' id='wrapper'>

            {loading && <Loading 
                client={this.state.client}
            />}

            <div className="content" id='page-wrapper'>
                <h1>Its ok for now ====</h1>

                <p>
                    {JSON.stringify(this.props.client)}
                </p>

                <div>
                    {!!this.props.client.info &&
                        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.client.info.SEO)}</p>} 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
</HtmlPage>
```

The `react-helmet-async` don't work.

https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a second `renderPass` to allow it to collect header elements. I tried `react-tree-walker` for this, but it didn't work. In the end I added a second renderPass using `renderToStaticMarkup`. E.g. 
`

```
const stream = renderToNodeStream(<App preloadedState={preloadedState} />);

// extra render pass
renderPass(<App preloadedState={preloadedState} />);
```

`